# Ionic : VirtualScroll and InfiniteScroll together on iOS not working

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, infinite-scroll, ionic3

i am trying to use VirtualScroll and InfiniteScroll together on iOS but seems InfiniteScroll not working with VirtualScroll. It's working fine in android.

```
<ion-content class="home">

    <ion-list [virtualScroll]="items" approxItemHeight="50px">
        <ion-item *virtualItem="#item">
            <ion-avatar item-left>
                <ion-img [src]="item.picture" width="48" height="48"></ion-img>
            </ion-avatar>
            <h2>{{item.name}}</h2>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>

 <ion-infinite-scroll (infinite)="doInfinite($event)">
   <ion-infinite-scroll-content></ion-infinite-scroll-content>
 </ion-infinite-scroll>

</ion-content>



doInfinite(infiniteScroll:any) {
     console.log('doInfinite, start is currently '+this.start);
     this.start+=50;

     this.loadPeople().then(()=>{
       infiniteScroll.complete();
     });

  }
```

Note :- Ionic version : 3.0.1